# CSS vertically align center font awesome icon to text

Tags: html, css, fonts, sass, font-awesome

I'm stuck, how can I vertically center the arrow no matter what the `<a>` tag font size is?

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, 'sans-serif';
}

a {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #000;
}

i {
  font-size: 12px !important;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
  <a href="#">View Full Chart <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: use vertical-align: middle; for i tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `i { vertical-align: middle; }`

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, 'sans-serif';
}

a {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #000;
}

i {
  font-size: 12px !important;
  font-weight: 300;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
  <a href="#">View Full Chart <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `vertical-align: middle;`

```css
body{
  font-family: Arial, 'sans-serif';
}
a {
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #000;
}
i {
    font-size: 12px !important;
    font-weight: 300;
    vertical-align: middle;
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <a href="#">View Full Chart <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add css `vertical-align:middle` to font awesome icon to vertically align the icon. I believe this was you were looking for.

JS fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/mpsingh2003/cbra9o2b/

Answer (score 1):

**Use:** `vertical-align: 50%;`

```css
body{
  font-family: Arial, 'sans-serif';
}

a {
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #000;
}

i {
    font-size: 12px !important;
    font-weight: 300;
    vertical-align: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href="#">View Full Chart <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```